# CSS submenu parent color on hover and position of submenus

Tags: css

this might be an easy one.

This is how my pure css menu currently looks like:

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

/* Menu */
.menu__wrapper {
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 8000;
 min-height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Main links */
.menu__mainlink {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  color: $dark-color;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Sublinks */
.menu__sublink {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.menu__mainlink, .menu__sublink:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}



/* Sticky header */
.menu__wrapper.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.sticky .dropdown .dropbtn, .sticky a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__wrapper padding-left-large sticky">
    <div class="dropdown no-padding-left">
      <a class="menu__mainlink" href="#">Main</a>
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Information</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Archiv</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Kontakt</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Impressum</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown no-padding-left">
      <a class="menu__mainlink" href="#">Program</a>
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <div class="dropdown-content show">
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">This</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">That</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Really_long_menu_item</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Calendar</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown no-padding-left">
      <a class="menu__mainlink" href="#">Found</a>
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Videos</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Image</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Sound</a>
          <a class="menu__sublink" href="#">Text</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Pen:** https://codepen.io/t-book/pen/yLNwRba?editors=1100

**Question 1:** How can I color red the parent menu item like "main" when hovering over its subitems (like Archiv or Kontakt)?

**Question 2:** How could I push the absolute positioned submenu left to align it under its parent? The moment I position the submenu relative it will keep the x of its parent but unfortunately, in case of really long submenu names, it pushes the next floated parent item right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer 1:

.dropdown:hover> a{color:red;}

### Answer 2:

- remove overflow:hidden; to .dropdown
- add position:relative; to .dropdown
- remove width: 100%; from .dropdown-content

Comment: Nice ! thanks a million @Ziad Darwich . Regarding two . When removing 100% from .dropdown-content the menu will not span across the full viewport anymore. do you see any way to keep the second row (submenus) full with but just move the sumbenu items left?

Comment: well there is no clear way for that especially if you aim to achieve that without JS, are you okay with adding some javascript? and is your dropdown dynamic or you know its height?

Comment: If you know its height check this solution forked from your own code: https://codepen.io/ziad-darwich/pen/PoqLgdB?editors=1100